# How can I skip the first line in CSV files imported into a pandas df but keep the header for one of the files?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I essentially want to preserve the header for one of the csv files to make them the column names in the csv but for the rest of the files I want to skip the header. Is there an easier solution to doing this except for the following:

- import as no headers, then change column names after all csv files are imported and deleted duplicate rows from df.

My current code is:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import os


path = r"C:\Users\..."

my_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "filename*.xlsx"))

file_li = []

for filename in my_files:
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, index_col=None, header=None)
    file_li.append(df)
```

I am trying to append 365 files into one based on the condition that the file name meets the above criteria. The files looks like this:

|  | Colunn1 | Colunn2 | Colunn3 | Colunn4 | Colunn5 | Colunn6 | Colunn7 | Colunn8 | Colunn9 | Colunn10 | Colunn11 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 6 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I want to keep the column names (column1, 2.,) for the first file but then skip it for the rest so I dont have to reindex it or change the df after. The reason for this is I dont want to have duplicate rows with column headers in the DF or have missing headers...is this complicating an easier solution?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you putting them in a list?
Pandas concat lets you combine DF's while doing the column name management for you.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html